# R: plot of normalmixEM shows truncated density plots (mixtools)

Tags: r, density-plot

I'm currently trying to plot the components found via EM algorithm. However, the estimated densities do not extend fully to the end. It looks like this:[image]

My code is:

```
plot(EM_data, which=2, xlim= c(0, 80), xlab2= "", yaxt= "n", main2 ="", lwd2=0.8, border = "azure3")
lines(density(EM_data), lty=2, lwd=0.8)
```

The plot is truncated wether I specify xlim or not. xlim2 is not defined for this type of plot. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The method to plot mixEM only draws within the range of the data, if you want to extend the densities you must build your own function.

Use something like this:

**Example data:**

```
library(mixtools)

data(faithful)
attach(faithful)
set.seed(100)
EM_data<-normalmixEM(waiting, arbvar = FALSE, epsilon = 1e-03)
```

**mixtools plot:**

```
plot(EM_data, which=2, xlim= c(30, 110), xlab2= "", yaxt= "n", main2 ="", 
     lwd2=0.8, border = "azure3")
lines(density(EM_data$x), lty=2, lwd=0.8)
```

[image]

**Adaptation by extending densities:**

```
a <- hist(EM_data$x, plot = FALSE)
maxy <- max(max(a$density), 0.3989 * EM_data$lambda/EM_data$sigma)
hist(EM_data$x, prob = TRUE, main = "", xlab = "", xlim= c(30, 110), 
     ylim = c(0, maxy), yaxt= "n", border = "azure3")
for (i in 1:ncol(EM_data$posterior)) {
  curve(EM_data$lambda[i] * dnorm(x, mean = EM_data$mu[i], sd = EM_data$sigma[i]), 
        col = 1 + i, lwd = 0.8, add = TRUE)
}
lines(density(EM_data$x), lty=2, lwd=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Juan, I was able to adapt the code to my data but I did not use the first two lines:
  a <- hist(EM_faithful$x, plot = FALSE) 
  maxy <- max(max(a$density), 0.3989 * EM_faithful$lambda/EM_faithful$sigma
It seems to me like you wanted to determine the point with the highest density? Am I right? I just don't see why, since there is no need to adapt the y axis? And where did you get the number 0.3989?
I'm sorry, I just don't understand all of it. I would appreciate any clarification, thanks a lot!

Comment: The reason is that I wanted to replicate exactly the plot you get with the library `mixtools`, and this library does this. But you're right, it's not necessary, it just slightly changes the aesthetic. The number 0.3889 is getting of the code the `mixtools`, see `plot.mixEM`.